# Updating Android device manager in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am new to mobile testing so last week I updated my Visual Studio 2019 to add **Mobile Development with .NET** via Tools-> Get Tools and Features

After a week playing around with it I am realizing that the latest OS of Android, 12.0, is not an option to pick from.  Here are the parameters I am currently seeing and using...

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question is, is there a way to update this so I can see and use Android 12.0 for devices?  I am not seeing any obvious update button anywhere.   I realize I could use Android Studio and that has the latest 12.0 version, but my question is for Visual Studio 2019 specifically.

Comment: upgrade to VS2022

Comment: @Jason  that may be what I end up doing. Thanks